# Simbolo inesperado, não consigo detectar?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProgramacaoParalela
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para iniciar");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Invocar os métodos que vamos executar
            Parallel.Invoke(
            new Action(exibirDias),
            new Action(exibirMeses),
            );

            // Aguardar a continuação do programa
            Console.WriteLine("\nO método Main foi encerrado. Tecle Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void exibirDias()
        {
            string[] diasArray = { "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta","Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo" };
            foreach (string dia in diasArray)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Dia da semana: {0}", dia);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static void exibirMeses()
        {
            string[] messArray = { "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr","Mai", "Jun", "Jul",
                                   "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dec" };

            foreach (string mes in messArray)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Mês : {0}", mes);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Nesse codigo acima não estou conseguindo ver onde esta meu ) que o compilador acusa com a seguinte mensagem:

main.cs(22,11): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retire a vigula desta linha
`new Action(exibirMeses)`**,**

Coloque **public** `static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: Obrigado! erro de iniciante.

Comment: @Fenix Se resolveu poderia aceitar m inha resposta :)

Comment: estava esperando passar os 5 minutos! Feito